# Checking for Multiple Guild ID's - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a welcome DM to users that join my discord server, but I have the bot setup in multiple servers. I'm trying to check the guild then send a message based on which guild it is in, but it's not working. I've looked and the popular question like this on stackoverflow uses commands and ctx, which cannot be used in `on_member_join()`.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(762921541204705321)
    if guild == 762921541204705321:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send("Welcome!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), when you call `get_guild()` it doesn't return the guild ID, it returns a `Guild` object.  [From the source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/guild.py), it appears that this guild class does have its comparison operator overloaded, so it cannot  deal with comparisons between a `Guild` object and an integer ID.

The solution to your problem is to just compare the number ID with the `Guild.id` attribute:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # client.get_guild returns a Guild object!
    guild = client.get_guild(762921541204705321)

    # Get the ID from the 'id' attribute on the guild object and compare.
    if guild.id == 762921541204705321:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send("Welcome!")
```

Comment: This works, but I added a second guild (guild2) and it always sends the first DM no matter what (never gets to the second elif). Here's what I have:
`@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild1 = client.get_guild(762921541204705321)
    guild2 = client.get_guild(593941391110045697)
    if guild1.id == 762921541204705321:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send("Welcome!")
    elif guild2.id == 593941391110045697:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(f"Welcome!")`

Comment: @MrMetacom create another post if you have another problem.  the code formatting doesn't work well in comments.

Comment: Alright. I accidentally posted a similar question just now so I'll have to wait an hour and a half.